# Bar plot error: incompatiable sizes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have the below code I am trying to bar plot but I keep getting the below error and I'm not sure why - all lengths (var_exp, eigen_values and cum_sum_var) are 18,093. What am I missing? I am using Python 2.7

> File "", line 2, in 
>       label='individual explained variance')
>
> File "C:\ANACONDA\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line
>   2573, in bar
>       ret = ax.bar(left, height, width=width, bottom=bottom, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\ANACONDA\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_axes.py", line
>   1991, in bar
>       nbars)
>
> > AssertionError: incompatible sizes: argument 'height' must be length
> >     13 or scalar

```
eigen_values, eigen_vectors = np.linalg.eig(covariance_matrix) 

tot = sum(eigen_values)
var_exp = [(i / tot) for i in sorted(eigen_values, reverse=True)]
cum_var_exp = np.cumsum(var_exp)

len(var_exp)
Out[83]: 18093

len(eigen_values)
Out[84]: 18093

len(cum_var_exp)
Out[85]: 18093

bar(range(1,14), var_exp, alpha=0.5, align='center',
                  label='individual explained variance')
step(range(1,10), cum_variance, where='mid',
     label = 'Cumulative Explained Variance')
ylabel('Explained variance ratio')
xlabel('Principal components')
legend(loc='bottom')
show()
```

Comment: I think we're missing the point on what you are trying to achieve here? Do you want to have a bar plot with 18093 bars? Or, if not, how should the bars be related to the data?

Comment: It's part of PCA code so I was hoping 1 to 14 would show the principal components along the x axis and the explained variance ratio on the y axis and the sum in the bars so I can see how much variance is explained for each principal component. You can see the chart I want for my data here (1/3 down the page): http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/scikit-learn/scikit_machine_learning_Data_Compresssion_via_Dimensionality_Reduction_1_Principal_component_analysis%20_PCA.php

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest edited comment above

Comment: So you have 18093 principle components but you only want to show the first 13 of them? In this case you may limit your list to 13 entries, `bar(range(1,14), var_exp[:13])`

Comment: That could be it! My laptop just decided to die and restart so I have to run the eigen values and vectors again but once it's processed I'll give this a go :-) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib's `bar` accepts these arguments

```
matplotlib.pyplot.bar(left, height, width=0.8, bottom=None, hold=None, data=None, **kwargs)
```

Where you are providing `left` as a range of 0-14 didgits whereas the height is set to an integer. Seems like `height` needs to be a `list` or `generator` of 13 digits.

Comment: Thank you; could you just clarify what you think needs to be a list?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @ImportanceOfBeingErnest! Your answer worked perfectly:

```
bar(range(1,14), var_exp[:13])
```

[image]